# How to change Back Ground color in Python app made with Qt Application

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to change the white background color to black and the black text into green text, I used PyCharm to write this code. Everything else is written in the code.

my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setGeometry(1200, 300, 500, 240)
    win.setWindowTitle("About my self")
    win.setWindowIcon(QIcon("app.jpg"))

    lbl_name2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_name2.setText("Age : 14")
    lbl_name2.adjustSize()
    lbl_name2.move(20, 60)

    lbl_name3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_name3.setText("Std. : 9")
    lbl_name3.adjustSize()
    lbl_name3.move(20, 80)

    lbl_name4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_name4.setText("School : N.P. BHalodiya High School")
    lbl_name4.adjustSize()
    lbl_name4.move(20, 100)

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



window()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `setStyleSheet` with the style `background-color: black;`, so after the statement `win = QMainWindow()` put this code:

```
win.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
```

Comment: Setting generic properties on windows or containers (and complex widgets) is always discouraged: [selector types](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) should be used instead. For instance, the code above will set the background on **all** its children (including elements that should probably not have the same background set, like the menubar, or the scroll bars of a scroll area). Assuming the QMainWindow has a central widget set (and it always should), the proper syntax of the above should be: `win.centralWidget().setStyleSheet('QMainWindow QWidget {background: black;}')`.